# How to convert a n1ql query to use with Spring couchbase reactive repository alongwith @Query annotation?

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-data-couchbase

I'm using Spring's reactive stack along with Spring's reactive couchbase to build api's and needing help in converting query which I want to use from ReactiveCouchbaseRepository.

approach for creating index in couchbase was taken from this post:
https://forums.couchbase.com/t/indexing-array-of-strings/14977

```
CREATE INDEX idx_emaillist ON api (DISTINCT ARRAY k FOR k IN emails.emaillist END);
```

query I am using to search is:

```
SELECT * FROM user AS u WHERE ANY k IN u.emails.emaillist SATISFIES k = "abc@email.com" END;
```

result of this query is:

```
[
  {
    "u": {
      "_class": "com.users.api.model.User",
      "name": "abc",
      "emails": {
        "emaillist": [
          "abc@email.com",
          ""xyz@email.com"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I would like to use the same query from a method declared in a interface that is extending ReactiveCouchbaseRepository.

I have also tried the approach specified in this ticket: 
[Can we Convert N1QL to shEL query for Spring use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55095570/can-we-convert-n1ql-to-shel-query-for-spring-use)

This approach works fine but I want Spring to take care of boiler plate code and also noticed that calls are blocking but I would like to have non blocking calls towards couchbase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find the answer to my question but after trying few more options found that I can do this by changing the format of my JSON object.

From:

```
[
  {
    "u": {
      "_class": "com.users.api.model.User",
      "name": "abc",
      "emails": {
        "emaillist": [
          "abc@email.com",
          ""xyz@email.com"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

TO this:

```
[
  {
    "u": {
      "_class": "com.users.api.model.User",
      "name": "abc",
      "emails": [
          "abc@email.com",
          ""xyz@email.com"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Now the method in the reactive couchbase repository is changed to:

```
    @Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} where #{#n1ql.filter} AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(emails, $1)")
    Flux<User> findByIdEmail(String email);
```

Further I checked the logs to see if thread is I/O thread or nio thread

```
DEBUG 19228 --- [reactor-http-nio-3] s.d.c.r.q.ReactiveAbstractN1qlBasedQuery : Executing N1QL query: {"args":["ABC"],"statement":"SELECT META(`user`).id AS _ID, META(`user`).cas AS _CAS, `user`.* FROM `user` where `_class` = \"com.users.api.model.User\" AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(emails, $1)","scan_consistency":"statement_plus"}
```

I hope this solutions helps other as well and not sure why I wanted to the structure with Object and then array.
Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any other properties related to an email, storing it as you did , in fact, is a better approach:

```
[
  {
    "u": {
      "_class": "com.users.api.model.User",
      "name": "abc",
      "emails": [
          "abc@email.com",
          ""xyz@email.com"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Note that you have to change your index also.

Here are some good links on how to create indexes for arrays:
https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/indexing-arrays.html
https://forums.couchbase.com/t/how-to-correctly-create-array-index/17349
https://blog.couchbase.com/making-the-most-of-your-arrays-with-array-indexing/

You can print the queries that are being generated by spring data:
https://blog.couchbase.com/how-to-log-queries-generated-by-spring-data/

and run the query with the "EXPLAIN" keyword to be sure that your query is using the index. If you are using the Enterprise edition, you can simply check the query planner.

Comment: thanks @deniswsrosa. I'll go with this solution itself. I had printed the query in my previous comment itself which was: Executing N1QL query: {"args":["ABC"],"statement":"SELECT META(`user`).id AS _ID, META(`user`).cas AS _CAS, `user`.* FROM `user` where `_class` = \"com.users.api.model.User\" AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(emails, $1)","scan_consistency":"statement_plus"}                           when I ran the query with "EXPLAIN" and it uses the primary index which is  "CREATE PRIMARY INDEX `#primary` ON `user`" so I think it is not using the index which i created so will drop the index.